# Check table box based on database value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table where students are rated based on how punctual, neat, attentive, or polite they are. The scale for rating is from 1-5 (SCALE: 5 = EXCELLENT, 4 = VERY GOOD, 3 = GOOD, 2 = PASS, 1 = FAIR).

So, if a student was rated 5 for punctuality, it records the number 5 both in the database and in view.

However, I would prefer a check to be shown instead of the numbers.

[checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuxei.jpg)

Controller

```
public function TeacherRating()
{
    $studentIds = $this->input->post('student_ids');
    $session_ids = $this->input->post('session_ids');
    $politenesses = $this->input->post('politenesses');
    $punctualities = $this->input->post('punctualities');
    $conducts = $this->input->post('conducts');
    $honesties = $this->input->post('honesties');

    $friendlies = $this->input->post('friendlies');
    $neatnesses = $this->input->post('neatnesses');
    $handwritings = $this->input->post('handwritings');
    $gameses = $this->input->post('gameses');

    $sportses = $this->input->post('sportses');
    $drawings = $this->input->post('drawings');
    $craftses = $this->input->post('craftses');
    $musicalskillses = $this->input->post('musicalskillses');
    $finalResults = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($studentIds); $i++) {
        $data['student_id'] = $studentIds[$i];
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `teacher_ratings` WHERE student_id='".$studentIds[$i]."'");
        $data['session_id'] = $session_ids[$i];
        $data['politeness'] = $politenesses[$i];
        $data['punctuality'] = $punctualities[$i];
        $data['conduct'] = $conducts[$i];
        $data['honesty'] = $honesties[$i];
        $data['friendly'] = $friendlies[$i];
        $data['neatness'] = $neatnesses[$i];
        $data['handwriting'] = $handwritings[$i];
        $data['games'] = $gameses[$i];
        $data['sports'] = $sportses[$i];
        $data['drawingpainting'] = $drawings[$i];
        $data['crafts'] = $craftses[$i];
        $data['musicalskills'] = $musicalskillses[$i];
        $inserted = $this->Comment_model->TeacherRating($data);
        array_push($finalResults, $inserted);
    }

    if ($finalResults > 0) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Teacher Rating Added Successfully');       
        redirect('rate/rate_students');
    }
}
```

This is my rating form

```
  <input type="number" max="5" min="1" name="politenesses[]" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;" value="<?php echo $student['politeness']; ?>"></td>
```

">

My view to display

```
 <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;">PUNCTUALITY</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"> <?php echo $teacher_rating->punctuality; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to make a very simple version of this based on sample data that you can hopefully integrate into your actual code. This is a very common programming task so it is a good one to learn and get down. The mixture of PHP and HTML can get ugly at times, so for the sake of clarity I personally prefer to use PHP's templating syntax. If you don't like it, you could also switch to `echo` or to use normal `{}` PHP syntax.

To start with, I'm going to create an array of attributes and possible scores. The attributes are a map of a human-readable label and an array index key name. The latter in your case could also be a database column instead.

```php
$attributes = [
    'Punctuality' => 'punctuality',
    'Honesty' => 'honesty',
];

$possibleScores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Next, I'm going to mimic your database and create a score for a single student across to attributes.

```php
$score = [
    'punctuality' => 2,
    'honesty' => 5,
];
```

Lastly, I'm going to render. The first loop just renders the column headers. The set of loops does each attribute one at a time, and then each score one at a time for the cells, comparing the cell's current value with the inner loop's current value and kicking out a checkbox when needed.

```php
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <?php foreach ($possibleScores as $possibleScore): ?>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $possibleScore; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($attributes as $label => $arrayIndex): ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $label; ?></th>
            <?php foreach ($possibleScores as $possibleScore): ?>
                <td class="checkbox">
                    <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="<?php echo $possibleScore ?>"
                        <?php if ($possibleScore === $score[$arrayIndex]): ?>
                            checked
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    />
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code above renders a table very similar to the below

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Punctuality |  | ✔ |  |  |  |
| Honesty |  |  |  |  | ✔ |

The above code is just an example. If you don't want true form checkboxes you can obviously just use images or whatever. If you keep this as a form and you want it to be editable (which I'm not clear on from your post), then you'd want to turn the checkboxes into radio buttons, and each row should be the same name. But that's another post.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started, but if I'm in the wrong direction completely just let me know.